# How can you get ScalaFX to play nice in the SBT console?

Tags: scala, javafx, sbt, scalafx

I'm writing an image library for intro programming students to play with. (I stole the idea and the patterns from the image library for DrRacket.)

https://github.com/dupontmanualhs/dm-image

It's mostly written in Swing (that's the `master` branch), but I'm trying to convert it to ScalaFX (see the `scalafx` branch), and there are some issues. Ideally, a student should be able to do something like:

```
scala> import org.dupontmanual.image._
scala> TrainEngine.display()
```

and have a dialog box with a train engine show up. I've tried using the code at

https://github.com/scalafx/ScalaFX-Tutorials

in the `stand-alone-dialog` project, but if I include `System.exit(0)` after I `dialog.showAndWait()`, I get this error:

```
Not interrupting system thread Thread[process reaper,10,system]
Exception while removing reference: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Not interrupting system thread Thread[Prism Font Disposer,10,system]
Exception in runnable
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
```

(Note that I get the same error if I try to run the `App` from `stand-alone-dialog` in the console, so I'm guessing that calling `System.exit(0)` is not a great idea in the SBT console.)

If I leave the `System.exit(0)` line out, then things seem to work fine--mostly. After the first time I display the dialog, it doesn't bring the dialog into focus, so I have to click it to dismiss the dialog. But the real problem is that when I `:q` to exit the console, SBT hangs and I have to `Ctrl-C` to be able to type again. (And, yes, `Ctrl-C` exits SBT completely, not just the console.)

I think what I may need to do is create a thread specifically for ScalaFX stuff. For example, I have a method to stack one image on top of another, and I got an `IllegalStateException` when I tried to call that function, even though it doesn't actually display anything, just creates a new `Group` with the two previous `Node`s stacked appropriately. Unfortunately, I'm not sure how to create a new thread and make sure that everything image-related runs through that.

I've already set `fork := true` in `build.sbt`, but that doesn't seem to make a difference with the console.

== Update ==

I found `initialCommands` and `cleanupCommands` in the SBT documentation and tried to clean up after everything when the console starts and ends. The values are:

```
initialCommands in console := """import org.dupontmanual.image._; org.dupontmanual.image.initialize()"""

cleanupCommands in console := """org.dupontmanual.image.cleanUp()"""
```

which are defined thusly:

```
package object image {
  var masterFrame: JFrame = _

  def initialize() {
    masterFrame = new JFrame()
    masterFrame.add(new JFXPanel())
    masterFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)
  }

  def cleanUp() {
    println("exiting platform")
    Platform.exit()
    println("disposing of frames")
    Frame.getFrames().foreach {
      _.dispose()
    }
    println("frames all disposed")
    System.exit(0);
  }
```

Here's the result of running the console and then trying to quit:

```
> console
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/sysadmin/dm-workspace/dm-image/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[info] Starting scala interpreter...
[info] 
import org.dupontmanual.image._
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_51).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> Hacker.display()

scala> :q
exiting platform
disposing of frames
frames all disposed
Not interrupting system thread Thread[XToolkt-Shutdown-Thread,5,system]
Not interrupting system thread Thread[AWT-XAWT,6,system]
Not interrupting system thread Thread[Prism Font Disposer,10,system]
Not interrupting system thread Thread[Java2D Disposer,10,system]
Exception while removing reference: java.lang.InterruptedException
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at com.sun.glass.utils.Disposer.run(Disposer.java:69)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Exception: sbt.TrapExitSecurityException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "run-main-0"
```

and that doesn't even exit the console. You still have to use Ctrl-C, which exits out of SBT completely.

Something is still running, but I can't figure out what it is. Grrr.

Comment: Have you tried calling `scalafx.Platform.exit()` instead of `System.exit(0)`? The former is the preferred method for terminating a _ScalaFX_ application.

Comment: Whoops! That should be `scalafx.application.Platform.exit()`! Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: I still get the problem where SBT hangs after I do `:q` in the console.

Comment: Yeah - I just tried using it in place of `System.exit(0)` in the _ScalaFX-Tutorials_ StandAloneFXDialog code and it just locks up the sbt console. According to the JavaFX version of this function (which ScalaFX calls under the hood), _Note: if the application is embedded in a browser, then this method may have no effect._ That could be a problem. I'll look into this some more...

Comment: I think the problem lies, not with `Platform.exit()`, but with the implementation of the `FXUtils.runAndWait(...)` function in the `stand_alone_dialog` package. In essence, it terminates the executing thread under a very limited set of conditions, so `Platform.exit()` ends up having no effect. I'm going to take a look at improving this. I'll place the revised code on [GitHub](https://github.com/MichaelJAllen/ScalaFX-Tutorials)...

Comment: Actually, upon further investigation, I think the problem is that this isn't really a ScalaFX/JavaFX application - it's a Swing application with some JavaFX stuff bolted into it. That probably why `Platform.exit()` isn't doing anything. If you look at the [documentation for the JavaFX JFXPanel class](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html) - for embedding JavaFX/ScalaFX into Swing applications - there is a neat worked example to follow. I guess since it's a Swing app, you terminate the app by calling the `dispose()` method of the main frame. Hope this helps...

Comment: Any idea what you do if there is no main frame (e.g., you just want to display an image in a dialog box)? And you should turn your last two comments into an answer. If they turn out to be the way to go, they'd be check-worthy. (Unfortunately, I'm brain-dead at the moment, so I'll try it in the morning.)

Comment: Good question. I think JFXPanel creates a Swing execution thread, and I'm not sure whether there's also a separate ScalaFX/JavaFX thread as well. I guess you could try calling `Platform.exit()` then `System.exit(0)` and see if that does the trick. BTW, I'll happily turn the comments into an answer when I figure out how you should terminate your app - but thanks! It shouldn't be _this_ hard... :-(

Comment: New idea... What would I have to do to create a new Scala/JavaFX Application and launch it from my `Image` class's `display()` method? I assume I'd have to run it in a new Thread or Process (because I tried just launching it without doing that and got an error).

Comment: OK. I've edited the question to reflect my latest attempts. Something seems to be starting a Thread that I can't access.

Comment: I guess you fixed it? Just checked out your project and ran the example, but no exception ;)

Comment: Oops, ignore what I said, after typing `exit` I see the error now, although I see it everytime I `exit` the sbt console, even when not executing the TrainEngine.

Comment: What is the reason you implemented it as a Swing app enclosing JavaFX, and not the other way around or JavaFX-only?

Comment: One of the ways to initialize the JavaFX toolkit is to create a JFXPanel. Unfortunately, that puts you into Swing/JavaFX hybrid-ness.

Comment: @OJKrylow, the error is because the JavaFX Toolkit gets initialized when the console is open, whether or not you actually use it. A similar error does not happen if you don't initialize the toolkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that you would somehow need to fork the console, so perhaps it's this issue: https://github.com/sbt/sbt/issues/1918

The following idea seems to work: Instead of the sbt console you embed a REPL, such as Ammonite. Still `sbt run` doesn't work, even with `fork in run := true`. But packaging a fat jar and running that does seem to work:

**build.sbt**

```
name := "Foo"

version := "0.1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-swing"   % "1.0.2",
  "com.lihaoyi"            %  "ammonite-repl" % "0.5.1" cross CrossVersion.full
)
```

**project/build.properties**

```
sbt.version=0.13.9
```

**project/plugins.sbt**

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.1")
```

**src/main/scala/foo/Main.scala**

```
package foo

import scala.swing._

object Main extends App {
  def test(): Unit = Swing.onEDT {
    new MainFrame {
      contents = new Label("App exits if you close window")
    } .open()
  }

  ammonite.repl.Main.run("")
}
```

Then

```
$ sbt assembly
...
$ java -jar target/scala-2.11/Foo-assembly-0.1.0.jar
Loading...
Welcome to the Ammonite Repl 0.5.1
(Scala 2.11.7 Java 1.8.0_66)
@ foo.Main.test()
```

The only oddity is that after the application exists, the shell character echoing is broken, perhaps that's an issue of Ammonite, you might want to try with the default Scala REPL.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I'm hoping the SBT people will eventually get around to fixing the bug.

Comment: I've been able to get ammonite working with scalafx as an standalone project as well https://github.com/wsargent/scalafx-ammonite